# Karma - mock attribute of child component in parent component spec file

Tags: karma-jasmine, viewchild

In my code i want to write a test case for a function in parent component . since i am setting a value to an attribute in child component ,while running karma suite for parent comp i am getting an error like attribute (child component ) is undefined .

```
In parentcomponent.ts
@Viewchildren(Childcomponent) childcomp : Childcomponent

getstatus()
{    
this.childcomp.empconfig1 = this.empconfig ( value in parent comp)
}
```

Now while running test case for parent component , i am getting empconfig1 undefined.

How to write a mock component for this child component in parent spec.ts file and set a value to **empconfig1** of child component